# Connect to websphere-MQ to few topics C#

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I have an application which connect to websphere-MQ and when I set one topic is working, but I want to connect to few Topics in one application.

Code in which I get messages looks:

```
 mqMsg = new MQMessage();
 opt = new MQGetMessageOptions();
 opt.Options = MQC.MQGMO_WAIT | MQC.MQGMO_BROWSE_NEXT;
 mqMsg.CorrelationId = IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQMI_NONE;
 mqMsg.MessageId = IBM.WMQ.MQC.MQMI_NONE;
 mqTopic.Get(mqMsg, opt);
 String message = mqMsg.ReadString(mqMsg.DataLength);
```

I try make topic string like that:

> TOPIC_1/TOPIC_2/TOPIC_3/TOPIC_4

but is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are TOPIC_1, TOPIC_2, TOPIC_3 and TOPIC_4 real topic strings?

If yes you subscribe using wildcard topic string `TOPIC*`.

If not then you can create a parent topic `PARENT` and add the these topics under that. So your topic strings would look:

```
PARENT/TOPIC_1
PARENT/TOPIC_2
```

and so on. Then you subscribe with topic string `PARENT/#`. This would get publications for all topics under `PARENT`.

Hope this helped.